# How do I get only one result using db_query()

Tags: 7, database

I am transitioning from 'old school' PHP MySQL methods of using `mysql_fetch_array()`, etc. and I am trying to be more Drupally by using the Database API in my modules.

I simply want to return and print out a value. For example:

```
$query = db_query("SELECT zip FROM {zipcodes} WHERE city = :city LIMIT 1", array(":city" => $city));
```

I know the value is there, I can access and print it by using traditional methods outside the database API.

`print $query->zip` is not working.

The API documentation is as clear as mud.

Can someone tell me the correct way to access these values?

Is there a good tutorial anyone could recommend as well?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you wish to fetch only one result you could use [fetchField](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementInterface%3A%3AfetchField/7) with `db_query` to fetch the result, e.g.:

```
$zip_code = db_query("SELECT zip from {zipcodes} WHERE city = :city LIMIT 1", array(":city" => $city))->fetchField();
```

You could also fetch the values retrieved from the query's returned result source using options like [fetchObject()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!prefetch.inc/function/DatabaseStatementPrefetch%3A%3AfetchObject/7) similar to methods of conventional PHP (`mysql_fetch_object`) coding like using and get results.

Comment: some constructive criticism on the downvote would be rather useful

Comment: None of the functions or methods you describe are available in Drupal 7. Your example will produce a fatal error. Also you seem to be mixing Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 code, hence the down vote

Comment: @Clive oops....blood rush... good to know the reason though..thanks!

Comment: No worries, if you fix up the answer I'll gladly remove the downvote

Comment: @Clive done it now... :)

Answer (score 16):

Here's how to use the Database API in Drupal 7 without writing a MySQL query:

```
$query = db_select('zipcodes', 'z')
  ->fields('z', array('zip'))
  ->condition('z.city', $city)
  ->range(0, 1)
  ->execute();
$result = $query->fetchObject();
print $result->zip;
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to loop your $query, you can't suppose you only have one result with the above given query.

```
foreach ($query as $row) {
  print $row->zip;
}
```

If you know you only have one result, you could call fetchObject on your query ->

```
$query = db_query("select zip from {zipcodes} where city = :city limit 1", array(":city" => $city))->fetchObject();
```

print $query->zip should then give you what you want.

Comment: Note: Instead of hardcoding a limit, you should use db_query_range().

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but you can and should do:

```
$zip_code = db_select('zipcodes', 'z')
    ->fields('z', array(
        'zip'
    ))
    ->condition('city', $city)
    ->range(0, 1)
    ->execute()
    ->fetchField();
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do

```
$row = (object)db_query('Your SQL here')->fetchAssoc();
```

if you want exactly one row from result set. Otherwise looping with foreach is the best option, as suggested before.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to ways to do this properly in Drupa 7:

1. db_select - in Drupal there is a function that return an object that you construct with him the SQL query - https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_select/7. You have a method on the object called range. you can use it.
2. Entity field query which is a class that construct a SQL query upon entites: https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708. This is also have the range method.

Answer (score 0):

**Drupal 7**

Use This Query For Single result:

```
$zip_code = db_query("SELECT zip from {zipcodes} WHERE city = :city", array(":city" => $city))->fetchField();
```

Instead of using this

```
$zip_code = db_query("SELECT zip from {zipcodes} WHERE city = :city LIMIT 1", array(":city" => $city))->fetchField();
```

because its generate warning.

Answer (score -2):

**Drupal 6**

`$query` will be your result
You need to fetch values from it,
In your case If it fetches only 1 row and 1 column i.e zip then to get directly

```
$zip = db_result(db_query("YOUR SQL QUERY"));
```

`$query->zip` will not work as $query is result set not a loaded object or an array.
So this should do

```
while($row = db_fetch_object($res)){
  $row->zip ; // etc
}
```

Note: `db_fetch_array` is another [API](http://drupal.org/node/310069) to fetch values in array format

Comment: db_result db_fetch_array and db_fetch_object are for Drupal 6 and earlier.