# How can I create a view page that takes taxonomy machine name and has depth?

Tags: 7, views, path-aliases

This question is a followup to [How to load nodes that are associated with the child of a taxonomy term](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197843/how-to-load-nodes-that-are-associated-with-the-child-of-a-taxonomy-term) and refers to [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/197847/52651) in particular, but is standalone, so you need only visit those if you want more background.

I want to create a view that functions like the Taxonomy term view that comes with views with depth turned on in the contextual filter, **but taking the term's machine name** instead of tid as the contextual argument.

[image: default Taxonomy term view]

I have pathauto set up to alias /taxonomy/term/tid to /vocabulary/term, and I would like to override the page there with views to make it show nodes associated with the children of the term as well as the parent.

So if I had the following Taxonomy:

**Vocabulary 1 (vocab_1)**

- Term 1 (term_1)

  - Term 2 (term_2)
  - Term 3 (term_3)
- Term 4 (term_4)

  - Term 5 (term_5)

and nodes as follows:

Node 1 - Term 2, Term 5
Node 2 - Term 5
Node 3 - Term 3

A visitor to /vocab_1/term_1 should get a list that contains nodes 1 and 3 because they are associate with children of Term 1.

I haven't been able to figure out how to do that with the term machine_name as the contextual filter instead of the tid.

Comment: "but taking the term's machine name instead of tid as the contextual argument" FYI: Terms don't have machine names.

Comment: Ok, not machine name, but whatever path auto generates for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the contextual filter **Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)** without adding a *Relationship*.  Use this settings for the contextual filter:

**When the filter value is *NOT* available**: Provide default value 
**Type**: Taxonomy Term ID from URL
Make sure *Load default filter from term page* is **checked**.

**Please note:** When you visit a pathauto destination path, in this case with a source of `/taxonomy/term/%` pointing at `/vocabulary_name/term_name`, drupal passes the source path as a query variable, and your view still uses the source path to gather information.  This means your path in the view should not change, it should stay as `taxonomy/term/%`

Comment: Will that give me depth?  All the modes will be associated with child terms of the term in the URL.

Comment: I've changed my answer, after reading your question once again.

Comment: As far as I can tell your answer is assuming the url contains a tid, but it doesn't.  It creates the term name as adjusted by pathauto.  I suppose it is possible that that somehow carries the tid along with it, so I'll look into it.

Comment: Reviewing this it seems not to take the name of the term, but instead expects the tid.  since I have pathauto set up to alias /vocabulary/termname to the term page this doesn't seem like it will work.

Comment: @UltraBob Yes it expects the tid, but it should work with pathauto.

Comment: In my testing it didn't.  It is possible that I did something wrong, but it seemed not to be able to know what term I was looking for when I used the pathauto converted term name.  I've been trying to write that functionality myself, so if you can confirm that it does actually work for sure, it could save me some time, to so figure out why my test didn't work when yours does instead of writing this custom code.

Comment: @UltraBob what are you using as contextual filter?

Comment: Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)
Content: Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier

as instructed in your answer as best I can tell

path: area/%

Comment: In the {url_alias} table I have source taxonomy/term/tid pointed at /area/term-name for terms in the area vocabulary

Comment: It takes the filter from the main url, not from the url generated by pathauto. That means if you visit 'taxonomy/term/1', and pathauto rewrites it as 'area/first', the view takes the argument '1', not 'first'.

Comment: I don't think that is how pathauto works (if I visit taxonomy/term/tid I get server the page at /taxonomy/term/tid, not redirected), perhaps you also have some kind of redirect module enabled? Also, I'm redirecting to the pathauto url from module code like so: `drupal_goto(drupal_get_path_alias('taxonomy/term/' . $tid), array(), 301);` after determining the tid.  The tid seems not to come through to views as far as I can tell.

Comment: I thought, you've set your page path in your views page settings as 'taxonomy/term/%'. At least, on the screenshot in your question, the path is 'taxonomy/term/%'. If you work with redirects, it won't work.

Comment: Hi, I misunderstood.  After I ran through the debugger and saw how it was routing things, I see as you were trying to explain, that my path needs to be set to /taxonomy/term/%.  Once I did that I get a list of nodes.  I just need to confirm that they are the right ones (the display is weird).

Comment: I just edited your answer to add the details that I was missing.  Have a look.  If you agree I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately looks like there isn't a term machine name contextual filter option. There is one, but only for vocabulary machine name.

If you really want this, you will have to get your hands dirty.

Create a custom module with a custom page that has a variable url. ex: `/taxonomy/%` the `%` being a place holder for the machine name.

Then on page load using using [current_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/current_path/7) along with some php function (perhaps [str_ireplace()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_ireplace.asp) to remove the `taxonomy/` part), you grab machine name from the url. Then you query the database, [using db_query()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7), to grab the term id that belongs to that machine name.

Once you have the term id you can render the view on your screenshot using php. So you just pass the term id as the argument.

```
<?php
print views_embed_view('my_view', 'block_1', $arg,);
?>
```

so in your case it would be:

```
<?php
print views_embed_view('taxonomy_term', 'page', $term_id,);
?>
```

---

#### Update:

> After looking at the taxonomy term table (taxonomy_term_data) turns
>   out that there is no machine name column for taxonomy terms (which explains
>   why there is no contextual filter in views).

Therefore, the only alternative would be to use the taxonomy term name. As long as you have unique term names, this will be fine.

First, you need to go to the taxonomy term view (the one in your screenshot) and press on [image] and add a block and save.

Here is a working module I created called term finder.

```
/sites/all/modules/term_finder
```

**term_finder.info**

```
name = Term Finder
description = Creates variable pages for taxonomy term names and shows a view.
core = 7.x
```

**term_finder.module**

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function term_finder_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['taxterm/%'] = array( // this will be our custom page url. The % allows us to put anything after, ex: taxterm/[anything can go in here]
    'title' => 'Your Title Goes Here',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page callback' => 'term_finder_page', // the name of the function that gets runed when we visit our taxterm/[anything] page.
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'menu' => 'navigation',
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Page callback for taxterm/%.
 */
function term_finder_page() {
  $path = current_path(); // gets the current page url. ex: taxterm/hello-world and saves it on a variable
  $path = str_ireplace('taxterm/','', $path); // removes the taxterm/ from our variable, so we are left with hello-world
  $path = str_ireplace('-',' ', $path); // replaces the - with a space, so we have hello world
  $term_id = db_query("SELECT tid from {taxonomy_term_data} WHERE name = :name LIMIT 1", array(":name" => $path))->fetchField(); // queries the DB to find the tid that belongs to hello world.
  if ($term_id != '') { // we check if grabbed a term id, is not empty.
    $show_view = views_embed_view('taxonomy_term', 'block_1', $term_id); // creates the view, which passes the tid we got from the DB as an argument.
    return $show_view; 
    }
  else { // if the term id is empty, then we show "not found".
  return 'not found';
  }
}
```

Lets assume you have a term called Hello World.

What this does is if you go to `/taxterm/hello-world` or (in firefox) `/taxterm/hello world`

It will look up in the DB for Hello World and get the term id and pass it to the view.

**PS:** In case you are wondering why the mysql query looks the way it does, see [Writing secure code](https://www.drupal.org/writing-secure-code) and [How do I get only one result using db_query()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23290/how-do-i-get-only-one-result-using-db-query)

Comment: Actually I'd love to do that, I just don't know where to get started with creating a module listening for a specific page.  I'll try to dig further into the docs to figure that out, but any pointers for the right place to look would be appreciated.  Being able to do that would let me avoid loading the views infrastructure until I am actually ready to render a page rather than when I'm still going to do a redirect.

Comment: I've been trying to follow the early examples [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), but every time I flush cache and load the new path that it seems my hook_menu should have created I get access denied and my function is never called.  I'm sure when I discover what I've been doing wrong it will have been something simple, but for tonight it has defeated me.

Comment: @UltraBob updated my answer, sorry for the delayed reply. Somehow I missed the comment notification.

Comment: You are my favorite person!  I can't figure out how one might pm here, but if you have an amazon wishlist or something I'd love to give something back.  This isn't exactly what I need, but it shows me everything I need to get there, and teaches me some extra important information in the meantime.  Thank you!  I'll go implement my version and come back and accept.

Comment: @UltraBob Thank you for the kind words, glad to hear my answer helped you in some way. I help people in here without the expectation of getting something back nor I want something back. I learned Drupal from the Community by watching videos tutorials, reading tutorials and reading Q & A's here. This is the beauty of Drupal, it has a great community.

Comment: The irc channels are next to useless in my time zone, so this is the best resource I know of for getting help, and you are consistently incredibly helpful.  Thank you again!

Comment: I forgot to ask, is there some particular reason why you used a block instead of a page?

Comment: @UltraBob I tried using page at first, but I kept getting a blank page when I did that. So looks like it only works with block.