# Webform draft share link

Tags: 7, users, webforms

I would like to create a webform which accepts input from two parties. First party fills out part of a form and share a link with second party to proceed with the rest.

I have found 'save draft' feature useful for this service but only loads pre saved info for the same person. Is there anyway I can share a link (based on sid) so that whenever the URL has a SID parameter, it loads pre saved info?

Thanks

Comment: you could save party 1 info on a custom DB table and then load the info when party 2 fills out their form.

Comment: @NoSssweat Thanks. I was thinking of creating a content type for the first party so it saves data on the same Drupal database. Can you please explain more about filling info for party 2? Not a fan of URLs with really long parameters. Is there a way to just call SID as parameter and load data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking of creating a custom module that creates **form 1** which saves the info in DB tables with a unique value of SID.

**Form 2**, which has url of `/example/%` the variable % being the sid.

loads info from db using the url parameter.

```
$sid = request_path(); // gets the current page url. ex: example/sid
$sid = str_ireplace('example/','', $sid); // removes the example/ from our variable, so we are left with sid
```

Now that you have the sid inside $sid, you can query the db to grab your fields.

EX:

```
$field1 = db_query("SELECT field1 from {table_name} WHERE sid = :sid LIMIT 1", array(":sid" => $sid))->fetchField();
```

**PS:** In case you are wondering why the mysql query looks the way it does, see [Writing secure code](https://www.drupal.org/writing-secure-code) and [How do I get only one result using db_query()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23290/how-do-i-get-only-one-result-using-db-query)

Comment: With custom module, are you saving data in a new custom table? And isn't SID always unique? Sorry I'm pretty new to Drupal. Should I insert the code you provided inside `form_alter` for Form 2? is `taxonomy_term_data` is same as the table name?

Comment: @user2574948 yes table_name, sorry, I copy pasted from another of my answers and modified, forgot to change that. Yes should go inside form_alter if you're altering a form.

Comment: @user2574948 I highly recommend you install the [examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module, which has good examples for creating forms. Then take a look at the source code to see how the example works.

Comment: I have installed examples module but can't see any links to tutorials. How can I use this module?

Comment: @user2574948 you need to enable "Form Examples" then in your "Navigation Block" you will see links to each example https://d08of.ply.st/. Then you just have to look at the source code in `/sites/all/modules/examples/form_examples` to see how it works.

Comment: performance wise is it ok to write a new query to each field?

Comment: @user2574948 it depends on many different factors. You can try it both ways, and use the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module to measure your query time.

Comment: Thanks I managed to save data in database. How can I customise Form 2 url? ex:- /example/%

Comment: add another set of `items['example2/%'] = array( ...` with a different page call back, inside your hook_menu()  [See this as an example](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/recurly/tree/recurly.module?h=7.x-1.x)

Comment: Thank you for your support so far. I only have one last thing to clarify. I can now register a URL. How can I load up form 2 for this URL? Do I need to create form on page callback? Please provide me an example if you can. Thanks.

Comment: @user2574948 my mistake, your page callback always is `'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',`. What you need to do is add a `'page arguments' => array('form_example_form'),` with the name of the function that has your form (this case being **form_example_form**). [See this tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/1419390) for more info.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain. Your code works perfectly fine. But not sure how to modify it to print parameter from URL. The reason is, now callback refers to the form function and it doesn't have code to print parameter.

Comment: @user2574948 use request_path(); or current_path(); to get the url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39536/discussion-between-user2574948-and-no-sssweat).